# How to superscript the count in an element of html

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my HTML website, I have created a circle in bottom left side of screen which has fixed position. The page has a check boxes. What I want is when user clicks on check boxes, the count of check boxes has to be shown as a superscript above the circle. (The way notification count shows up on facebook).

I have used span and css to draw circle and tried using `<sup>` but the place count value is displayed changes as font of span changes.

What is the best practice to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain 2 separate div(s). One for the base (the circle) and one for the superscript and specify the position and dimensions for both of them thus making their position fixed. Here's a snippet:

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;border-radius:50px;display:inline-block;text-align:center;position:relative;top:0px;right:0px;">
  <div style="background-color:yellow;position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;display:inline-block;">
    2
  </div>
  <!-- Content goes here-->
  App
</div>
```

Make sure that the inner DIV has an ABSOLUTE position so that it's position is not affected by the contents inside your circle.
Cheers! :)